# Yii - Display Many to Many Attribute in DetailView

Tags: yii2

I have these three tables as shown below

[image: ManyToMany]

courses and instructors tables are linked together in course_instructors

**Model: Course**

```
    public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('course', 'Course ID'),
        'course_name' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Name'),
        'course_code' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Code'),
    ];
}

public function getCourseInstructors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CourseInstructors::className(), ['course_id' => 'id']);
}
```

and also

**Model:Instructor**

```
    public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'instructor_id' => Yii::t('ins', 'Instructor ID'),
        'first_name' => Yii::t('ins', 'First Name'),
        'middle_name' => Yii::t('ins', 'Middle Name'),
        'last_name' => Yii::t('ins', 'Last Name'),            
    ];
}

 function getInstructorFullName()
 {
    return ($this->first_name." ".$this->middle_name." ".$this->last_name);
 }
```

Then,

**Model: CourseInstructors**

```
    public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'Course Instructor ID',
        'course_id' => 'Course',
        'instructor_id' => 'Course Instructor',
        'remark' => 'Remark',
    ];
}

public function getCourses()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Courses::className(), ['id' => 'course_id']);
} 

public function getInstructors()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Instructors::className(), ['instructor_id' => 'instructor_id']);
}
```

**CourseControllers**

```
    public function actionView($id)
{

        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $courseinstructors = $model->courseInstructors;

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
            'courseinstructors' => $courseinstructors,
        ]);
    }
```

**Detail View: course**

```
    <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'options'=>['class'=>'table  detail-view'],
    'attributes' => [
        'course_name',
        'course_code',
    ],
]) ?>

<h2>Details</h2>
<table class="receipt-details table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Instructor Name</th>
        <th>Remark</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($model->courseInstructors as $courseInstructor) :?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $courseInstructor->id ?></td>
            <td><?= $courseInstructor->instructor_id ?></td>
            <td><?= $courseInstructor->remark ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

From my Course Detail view, I want to display the instructor fullname

```
     function getInstructorFullName()
 {
    return ($this->first_name." ".$this->middle_name." ".$this->last_name);
 }
```

instead of the instructor_id in the Course Detail View

```
<td><?= $courseInstructor->instructor_id ?></td
```

**This is what am getting**

[image: Detail View]

The question is how do I display the instructor full name in the course detail view instead of the instructor_id, since it is many to many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in the Detail View:
`<td><?= $courseInstructor->instructors->first_name ?></td>` for first name.

`<td><?= $courseInstructor->instructors->last_name ?></td>` for last name.
You can join the name string to make a full name.

This comes from

```
public function getInstructors()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Instructors::className(), ['instructor_id' => 'instructor_id']);
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the framework power and consume the relations for the `ActiveRecord` models. Change your line from

```
<td><?= $courseInstructor->instructor_id ?></td>
```

to the following

```
<td><?= $courseInstructor->instructors->first_name.' '.$courseInstructor->instructors->last_name ?></td>
```

a better way would be to add the following method inside the model `Instructors`

```
public function getFullName(){
   return $this->first_name.' '.$this->middle_name.' '.$this->last_name;
}
```

and then use it like

```
<td><?= $courseInstructor->instructors->fullName ?></td>
```